# Docker doesn't install correct on Mac

Tags: macos, docker

I have a pretty fresh Macbook Pro. Just downloaded the Docker installer and ran it. Then I opened the quickstart app, which had some errors.

I'd show you what it said but it doesn't make the same errors the second time around. Here's what it shows the second time I open the quickstart app:

```
Machine default already exists in VirtualBox.
Starting machine default...
exit status 1
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
Setting environment variables for machine default...



                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/


host is not running
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

default is not running. Please start this with docker-machine start default
bash-3.2$ docker-machine env
Error: Expected either one machine name, or -u flag to unset the variables in the arguments.
```

And here's what happens when I try to run docker:

```
docker run hello-world
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

I thought Docker was supposed to be really great (everyone seems to love it), but this is really confusing sice I followed all the instructions.

EDIT: I am using Mac OS 10.10.3 and VirtualBox 5.0.3

Comment: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1716

Comment: The `docker` CLI can't run without `docker-machine env` because it needs those environment variables to learn where the docker daemon is running. Since there is no `env`, the `docker` CLI defaults to trying to use a unix socket, but on a Mac, there is no unix socket to talk to the daemon -- the daemon is running in a virtual machine and can only be reached via a TCP socket. The `env` would set the location of that tcp socket.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I upgraded VirtualBox to 5.0.3, same problem happens.

Comment: @Andy Thanks, I know that is the problem, my question is that I did everything in the installation instructions and still am stuck, so what can I do to get unstuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run from the your shell:

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

or you can set the same on your `.bash_profile` file.

You can see env variables if you just run the `docker-machine env default` command:

```
$ docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/user/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Don't forget to start your `docker-machine` (aka boot2docker)

```
$ docker-machine start default
```

You can also checkout the docker-machine subcommand reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/)

Comment: Someone else told me to do that, but there's an exception.

My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ eval $(docker-machine env default)
open /Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/default/ca.pem: no such file or directory

My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ docker-machine env default
open /Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/default/ca.pem: no such file or directory

Comment: Looks like your docker-machine didn't get created.  Did you try `docker-machine ls`  then perhaps `docker-machine rm default` if you have a `default` machine and then `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`, you can also try creating another machine with a different name other than `default`.

Comment: Well, that worked. The key was upgrading VirtualBox slightly and then doing what Rico said. This was one of the worst installation experiences ever, so unhelpful error messages. Thanks Rico.